# How to subtract the Number in Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

**How to subtract the number in a Robot Framework?**
What is the command for it?

For example, if I am getting a count, I want to subtract -1 and map keywords with the resulting value.

Comment: can any one give me suggestion for it.

Answer (score 15):

If your variable contains an actual number, you can use [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax). For example, this test will pass:

```
*** Variables ***
| ${count} | ${99} | # using ${} syntax coerces value to number

*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | Should be equal as numbers | ${count-1} | 98
```

You can also use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to create a python expression. For example:

```
*** Variables ***
| ${count} | 99

*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | ${count}= | Evaluate | ${count} - 1
| | Should be equal as numbers | ${count} | 98
```

Note: using [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) will work whether `${count}` is a number or the string representation of a number.

Answer (score 7):

You could use Evaluate keyword:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Stackoverflow
    ${x} =      Set Variable    1
    ${y} =      Evaluate    ${x} - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An expression like this should work:

${token_expire_time} =   Evaluate  ${token_generate_time}-${expires_in}

Answer (score -2):

If for some reason the conversion with ${} doesn't seem to work, then feel free to use:

[Convert to integer keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Integer)

or

[Convert to number keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Number)

Comment: avoid _link-only answers_ because links could be broken in future, please update your answer by adding the main informations.